# Fast scan of emails using IMAP protocol

Tags: email, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I am using IMAP protocol to scan emails for my inbox.
Want to write an application which will have all my newsletter sorted.

What I notice that it is get 1 sec for scan 1 email. But how service like UnRoll.me do in in 2 min?
Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more detail by what you mean by 'scan'.  What language and/or library are you using?  What is your code that is so slow?

Answer (score 1):

[psychic debugging hat on]

Likely, you are fetching messages one at a time, rather than sending requests for hundreds of messages at a time.  The `FETCH` can take a large list of (U)IDs, and you can get hundreds of responses for the cost of one network round trip:

```
 A001 FETCH 1:1000 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (.....)])
```